# What is the general term used for these pictured symbols?

Tags: msvc

I see these in VC++ compiled programs often. However, I've searched for several of them, such as AVCCHKBOX@@ and AVCDLC_NAME@@ to no avail. What are these called?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These strings are part of the *Run-Time Type Information (RTTI)* produced by Visual C++ for polymorphic classes. This old article of mine describes some of it: http://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/23

Comment: Thanks. What happened to that site, btw??? A lot of these re sites just suddenly seemed to cease activity.

Comment: people have lives.

Comment: quit being so optimistic :)